# Cant get jquery.data() or .attr() to work both return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I've read other questions regarding `.data()` and `.attr()` none of the answers have helped me.

I have a table with some buttons each button has its own id in the format:
`player-*****` where `*****` is a numerical id.

I also have some hidden form elements, I'm trying to:

- Read the values from the form element
- generate the reference to my div e.g `'#draftBtn-*****'`
- get the data attached to the button.
- Do something with the data....

I cant seem to get the data attached to my div, always returns undefined.

both`.attr('player-data')` or `.data('player)` are returning undefined.

I am using jQuery v1.12.0

sample row from table:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="label label-primary">TE</span></td>
    <td>Richard Rodgers</td>
    <td><b>GB</b> @ ARI</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>5100</td>
    <td>
        <div id='draftBtn-633397' class='btn btn-sm btn-success draft-player' data-player='{
            "id" : 633397,
            "player" : 16491,
            "shortName" : "R.Rodgers",
            "name" : "Richard Rodgers",
            "team" : "GB",
            "opponent" : "ARI",
            "position" : "TE",
            "salary" : 5100,
            "lastGameFantasyPoints" : "5",
            "projectedFantasyPoints" : "3",
            "opponentRank" : "8",
            "opponentPositionRank" : "19",
            "status" : "Scrambled",
            "statusCode" : "P",
            "statusColor" : "green"
        }'>+</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

my javascript:

```
var squadPlayers = {
    'qb': null,
    'rb1': null,
    'rb2': null,
    'wr1': null,
    'wr2': null,
    'te': null,
    'k': null,
    'flex': null,
    'def': null
};

var getPosKeys = function(){
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in squadPlayers) {
        if (squadPlayers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

var initSquad = function(){
    var keys = getPosKeys();
    console.log(keys);    
    keys.forEach(function(element) {
        var formRef = '#contestEntry_' + element;
        console.log(formRef);
        var playerID = $(formRef).val();
        console.log({'playerID': playerID}); // 633397
        var btnRef = '#draftBtn-'+playerID;
        console.log({'btnRef' : btnRef }); // '#draftBtn-633397'
        var playerAttr = $(btnRef).attr('data-player');
        console.log(playerAttr); // undefined
        var playerData = $(btnRef).data('player');
        console.log(playerData); // undefined

       //do something with the data.....        
       //addPlayerToSquad($)
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Use `dataset` native property. In this case will be `$(selector).get(0).dataset.player`

Comment: Shouldn't .attr('player-data') be .attr('data-player')?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Yes, and in the actual code further down it is

Comment: Can you also log `$(btnRef).length` - make sure it's actually finding the element in the first place?  Are you sure the element is there and populated when this code runs?

Comment: Do you execute this on dom ready using `$(function() { ... });`?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Use `data()` and jQuery will convert json to object automatically

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/c4fcyuLh/). Given that `playerID` is indeed `633397`, and that the HTML you've pasted is available in the DOM when the code is executed, neither `attr` or `data` will yield undefined. Thus, whatever is causing your code to log undefined, it is something outside of the code you've pasted, or the aforementioned prerequisites stated are not fulfulled (is the table populated by an AJAX call, and you're not using callbacks?)

Comment: @JamesThorpe '$(btnRef).length' returns '0 'so somethings not right, the div with that reference is on the page and its all wrapped in a '$(document).ready(function( )};'

Comment: Thanks for your help people , I think I have some problem with the actual values i'm using in the hidden form fields, not matching with the actual ID's of the buttons, need to dig around some more

Answer (score -4):

**FROM COMMENTS** (use the button as event):

so instead from the table-row, I'm *now* using the button as the trigger for the event, a simple test will show all works well:

```
$(function() {

  $(".btn").click(function() {
      var tr = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:last div"),
        json = tr.data("player");

     alert('ID: ' + json.id + '\nTeam: ' + json.team);
 });

});
```

LIVE Example: http://jsbin.com/kojunibixa/1/edit?html,js,output

*P.S.* I still don't understand the hole idea of complicating what's easy to do... Sorry.

Comment: I need to be able to use $(this) on functions I have attached to the button click so attaching the data to the <tr> does not help me much. (wasn't me who down voted)

Comment: An opinion on where to place the data attribute doesn't answer the question.  It would marginally be ok on an answer that _does_ answer the question, but the rest of your answer is essentially a comment that says "your code is ok", of which there are plenty under the question already.  If you want to answer "your code works", you should instead be voting to close as offtopic, "why isn't this code working".

Comment: @DizzyBryanHigh I still don't get it, but I've updated the code to be used with the button on each row...